# OnPress fails when executing conditional statements

Tags: reactjs

```
onPress={() => {
  const { calculatedistance } = this.state;
  if (calculatedistance < 1000 || calculatedistance > 30000) {
    this.snackbarref.current.triggeranimate("Please select valid location");
  } else {
    this.tooglebook();
  }
}}
```

When I click the on press function both the if and else body content is executing

Comment: maybe ```tooglebook``` does the same thing as the if statement.

Comment: no i checked@JuniusL.

Comment: console.log some message in both if and else and check if both messages appear on single key press.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't show error in console or can't clarify error, put your function body to `try/catch` block and log error like this:

```js
onPress = {() => {
    try {
      if (this.state.calculatedistance < 1000 || this.state.calculatedistance > 30000) {
        this.snackbarref.current.triggeranimate('Please select valid location')
        return;
      } else {
        this.tooglebook()

      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }

  }
}
```